# Magento changing A4 pdf invoice to foldable a6 showing address in 1 corner quarter of the paper

Tags: orders, extensions, invoice

**How can I: Change the A4 pdf invoice to foldable a6 showing address in 1 corner quadrant of the paper. Is there an extension that can do this?**

Hi, it took some time thinking of a good title. I will try to explain

*Current method*
Now we print the default Magento invoice on A4 paper. Top left address, company info on the right. Then a table with products.

*New method*
What we would like is using one quarter of the A4 (A6 size) to print the address and showing all the other order details below the middle fold. This way when we fold the A4: the address is shown in the top left corner.

*Why?*
Currently we print an invoice. We use it for order picking. Then we take a pen and write the address on a sticker (faster than dymo). The disadvantages of this process adre:

- Writing or printing the address costs extra time
- Writing or printing the address can cause typing mistakes
- Sometimes stickers and orders are mismatched (wrong address on order pick)
- We believe in LEAN operation: information transfer and split processed cause mistakes (and this does sometimes happen)

Below I have added an example

**CONCEPT**

[image: CONCEPT]

**BEFORE**

[image: EXAMPLE OF BEFORE]

**AFTER - SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

[image: EXAMPLE OF AFTER]

Comment: First, tell you customer/boss this will take A LOT of time. More than he can imagne. Then have a look on Zend_Pdf, maybe start with firegento_pdf and buy lots of red bull... changing pdf layouts is horrible.

Comment: Got that. I started some fiddling - it is just too much work .... there must be a better way.     btw I found this: http://www.aromicon.de/magento-download-extensions-modules/en/aromicon-invoice-pdf-pro.html     Looks quite good. And steady.

Comment: @Fooman has an invoice extension too: store.fooman.co.nz/ But I never heard of an extension which does anything like you want. But I think this is achievable in a few days with firegento_pdf ;-) the biggest problem is turning the text. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363460/how-to-rotate-text-while-creating-pdf-in-zend-framework

Comment: ha! I just found that too - rotating is quite a task in zend_pdf + now I am finding out how to rotate it *back* after the 90* print. And letting Magento not loose its bearings ($this-> and $top). I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help

Without Red Bull - but some new Grolsch Radlers (dutch beer) ...

The result is shown below (screenshot)

I stopped at getting the table data items -> just too much work to get it working ...

[image]

Some things I encountered

- the coding is ...
- there is no 1 code for the invoice, some is shared
- you need to override abstract.php + also a little of invoice.php (and be careful that there is no extension overriding the invoice.php (like Fooman pdf attachment))
- when you rotate, don't forget to rotate back using *the same* coordinates
- The shipping address is better built up manually

Hope it helps someone

---

I made a code gist here for who ever is interested: https://gist.github.com/seansan/a1a4608aad75de0acbd3

You could theoretically paste the code gist into your app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

and your invoice should look like mine

(maybe add a return pdf after InsertOrder call from invoice.php)

Comment: Try fooman pdf  or something similar. The advantage is that it uses tcpdf so you can build the invoice as html. Not sure if it can handle rotations via css, but if it can, i think it might be easier to maintain on the long run